# How to get remote config value by language in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web, firebase-remote-config

I've tried to find a reference for fetching a string value from remote config by language.

Per keys has a value per language. For example, the key 'tooltip_title' has the default value 'This is a tooltip title', and for Korean '이건 툴팁 제목이야'. is there a way to fetch the value that matches the language that I pass as a parameter?

Comment: Which software language, which platform?

Comment: @mzdogan using javascript and platform is web